# Reference to construct a mini c++ code generation

Tags: visual-studio, compiler-construction, code-generation, bison, lex

I'm trying to build a c++ compiler. I've built the syntax and semantic rules using lex and Bison on Visual studio, so the next step is to build the code generation. Is there any online reference that helps me to build the code generation?
any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm a little surprised you're using Lex and BISON. I don't think C++ can be fully parsed within the constraints of BISON because C++ needs too much knowledge about previously parsed entities, and several passes to correctly parse a program. Have you tried your parser on real source files and ensured that it works? With namespaces and nested classes and all that ... ?

Comment: @uliwitness actually i did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I blogged about various aspects of writing a compiler a while ago:

http://orangejuiceliberationfront.com/how-to-write-a-compiler/

I also wrote about how objects are laid out in RAM:

http://orangejuiceliberationfront.com/runtime-time/

Is that the kind of info you're looking for? I suppose my entire language design section on my blog (http://orangejuiceliberationfront.com/category/language-design/) would be of interest in that case. It's MacOS-centric, but the general basics of generating Intel machine code etc. are the same no matter what platform you're on.

Of course, the only hard specification of how to write a **C++** compiler is the ISO C++ standard specification, which you can probably buy for an insane amount of money from the ISO web site. But that specification of course assumes you know how to write a compiler.

Comment: actually I need the whole steps (a-z steps) to construct the code generation using lex analiser and bison parser.

Comment: There's not much to it. BISON lets you specify code that returns something, so just define the data types for your AST (syntax tree), and create objects of that type in the BISON file, then plug in the parameters (I think BISON uses $1 and $2 and the like for that...? Or maybe %lhs or so ?), then return that object. At the end you'll have the syntax tree from which you can generate your code.

Comment: I said I want to build the code generation for my mini c++ language. What's is the steps not only using lex and bison, using virtual machine (vm) for example?

Comment: My "how to write a compiler" article that I linked to describes this.